# how do I query mysql table with array?

Tags: php, mysql

$array contains multiple values for example $array = mathew,thomas,ethan,joseph;

I need to do a mysql query with all names and retrieve its individual values.

Answer (score 2):

```
"WHERE name IN ('" . implode("','", array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $array)) . "')"
```

By adding the quotes this way (use copy paste the quotes may be hard to see) it will let you match strings, and it will escape them as well.

If it's just numbers you can do the simpler:

```
"WHERE name IN (" . implode(",", $array) . ")"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query="SELECT * FROM tablw WHERE username IN(".array_map(function($x){
    return '"'.$x.'"'; // add quotes
},implode(',',$array)).")";
// now you can execute query
```

Don't forget to escape all data (You can do it in `array_map`)